# RestClient throws some error in Ruby

Tags: ruby

My code throws an error but I don't know why that error occurs

```
require 'rest_client'

response = RestClient.get 'http://example.com/resource'
puts response.code
```

Output:

```
 i.rb:3:in `<main>': uninitialized constant RestClient (NameError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using the 'rest-client' gem and not 'restclient'.